# Remove elements from Javascript array which is there in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I wrote a javascript function in my Angularjs application. Simply what i need to do is remove all items in arr1 which also have in arr2 (duplicate in arr2).

```
//array1 = array1 - array2
        $rootScope.removeArrayDuplicated = function (arr1, arr2) {
            console.log('before');
            console.log(arr1);
            for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
                Inner:  for (var j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {

                    if (arr2[i].name == arr1[j].name) {
                        console.log("inside " + arr2[i].name + " " + arr1[j].name);

                        arr1.splice(j, 1);
                        j--;
                        break Inner;
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log('after');
            console.log(arr1);
            return arr1;
        }
```

I print before value and after values of arr1. But i get the same array for both before and after arrays.I may done a mistake. please show me that.

*The arrays contains json objects

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6hwkxxsg/1/

Comment: Try something simple like return arr1.filter((item) => {  return arr2.indexOf(item) === -1; })

Comment: [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs#differenceBy)`.differenceBy(arr1, arr2, 'name')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
$scope.removeArrayDuplicated = function(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.filter(item => !(arr2.some(item2 => item.name === item2.name)));
}
```

[Here is a working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/yqwemswh/2/)

Here is es5 code transpiled via Babel

```
$scope.removeArrayDuplicated = function (arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.filter(function (item) {
    return !arr2.some(function (item2) {
      return item.name === item2.name;
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: I'm looking forward to IE and Safari supporting arrow functions. . .

Comment: @mgilson Most people are using babel to use newer js features.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy if you use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var newArr = arr1.filter(function(item) {
  return arr2.indexOf(item) == -1;
});
```

It looks like you're "de-duping" based on the item's name.  I might put all the names in a map for faster lookup:

```
var dedupe = function(arr1, arr2) {
  var nameMap = {};
  arr2.forEach(function(item) {
    nameMap[item.name] = true;
  });
  return arr1.filter(function(item) {
    return !!nameMap[item.name];
  });
});
```

This second version should scale as O(N) (opposed to the original which scales as O(N^2)).

Answer (score 0):

Are you required to edit the original array or can you construct a new output array?

If you can construct a new output array, this is what you're looking for:

```
    $rootScope.removeArrayDuplicated = function (arr1, arr2) {
    var outputArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        var duplicate = false;
        Inner:  for (var j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {

            if (arr2[i].name == arr1[j].name) {
                console.log("inside " + arr2[i].name + " " + arr1[j].name);
                duplicate = true;
                break Inner;
            }
        }

        if(!duplicate) {
            outputArray.push(arr2[i].name);
        }
    }
    return outputArray;
}
```